Does metered billing in Cashier 10 use legacy or new Meters?
Metered billing is available in Cashier 10. The documentation advises to setup the product first in the console, however when you are doing this you are prompted to chose between the new style Meters, and legacy metered usage.
Which one should I chose to be able to use the Cashier methods?

Cashier uses fixed Stripe versions.  Both the versions of Cashier for Laravel 10 and 11 use 2023-10-16.  The new meters were released on March 26 2024 so are not yet supported by Cashier.
